# CSS· transitions and animations not working in IE10+

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

I developed a page with several animations using CSS3 and is working correctly on all modern browsers, with the exception of IE. I don't expect it to work on older versions, but checking the W3C documentation for the CSS properties I used, they should be working even without vendor prefixes. Even so, I included all of the vendor prefixes for all of the properties that apply.

I mainly used keyframes to achieve some transitions like a spin, pendulum and blink. At this point I would be glad if I can get at least a couple of them to work.

**You can see the page in action here:** 
http://tiempo-libre.com.ve/prueba/

**The stylesheet with the CSS3 properties is:**
http://tiempo-libre.com.ve/prueba/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

You've got some of your animation names in double quotes "blink" especially the -ms- prefixed ones.

Also just to be super sure, check this article by Chris Coyier, it's pretty sweet -
[Keyframe animations](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I must have missed that double quote detail. I checked out the post on css-tricks.com and saw that I had already tried that without luck. However I noticed that in his example he uses  `-animation: fontbulger 2s infinite;` so I tried without the dash and it worked.

Comment: No problems dude and nice!